# Two's complement involving binary numbers

Tags: binary

$$0010\ 0100\ 1001\ 0010\ 0100\ 1001\ 0010\ 0100$$ What decimal number does it represent, assuming it's a two’s complement integer?

Comment: Im so confused. I dont understand

Comment: I do not either (your question, that is).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert the two's complement number $0010~0100~ 1001~ 0010~ 0100~ 1001~ 0010~ 0100$ to decimal.

The leftmost bit is a zero, which tells us that it is a positive number. If it were a $1$, it would be a negative number.

To convert a positive two's complement number to decimal number, we simply convert from binary to decimal. If it were a negative two's complement, we invert each of the bits and add $1$.

Since this is a positive number, we simply convert from binary to decimal and this gives:

$$0010~0100~ 1001~ 0010~ 0100~ 1001~ 0010~ 0100 = 613566756_{10}$$

Perhaps you should review this [*web site*](http://sandbox.mc.edu/~bennet/cs110/tc/tctod.html) or this [*web site*](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/~tomf/notes/cps104/twoscomp.html).

Comment: I did check and also used a 32 bit Two's complement to decimal converter and it gave me a different value. :(

Comment: Thank you. So basically the answer is 3681400540 ?

Comment: But wait, on the website you gave it says that when its "1" then we invert and add one , but when it starts with "0"  we simply convert it to decimal. the number i gave starts 0, so why did we have to invert each of the bits?

Comment: Yes, im sorry if im bothering, but to get the 613566756 , i have to do alot of calculation.

Comment: Did you try writing it as a hex number first and then converting that? That should be much easier.

Comment: I converted the number to hex and got 24924924 , and then to convert it into decimal, i have to get each number and multiply it (16^0,16^1) but when i added the numbers altogether i dont get the 613566756 :(

Comment: See this [*WA*](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=4+16%5E0+%2B+2+16%5E1++%2B+9+16%5E2+%2B+4+16%5E3+%2B+2+16%5E4+%2B+9+16%5E5+%2B+4+16%5E6+%2B+2+16%5E7)